# Why is there a difference in the task/microtask execution order when a button is programmatically clicked vs DOM clicked?

Tags: javascript

There's a difference in the execution order of the microtask/task queues when a button is clicked in the DOM, vs it being programatically clicked.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Promise.resolve().then(function() { console.log('resolved-1'); });
  console.log('click-1');
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Promise.resolve().then(function() { console.log('resolved-2'); });
  console.log('click-2');
});
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Click me !</button>
```

My understanding is that when the callstack is empty, the event loop will take callbacks from the microtask queue to place on the callstack. When both the callstack and microtask queue are empty, the event loop starts taking callbacks from the task queue.

When the button with the id `btn` is clicked, both "click" event listeners are placed on the task queue in order they are declared in.

```
// representing the callstack and task queues as arrays
callstack: []
microtask queue: []
task queue: ["click-1", "click-2"]
```

The event loop places the `"click-1" callback` on the callstack. It has a promise that immediately resolves, placing the `"resolved-1" callback` on the microtask queue.

```
callstack: ["click-1"]
microtask queue: ["resolved-1"]
task queue: ["click-2"]
```

The `"click-1" callback` executes its console.log, and completes. Now there's something on the microtask queue, so the event loop takes the `"resolved-1" callback` and places it on the callstack.

```
callstack: ["resolved-1"]
microtask queue: []
task queue: ["click-2"]
```

`"resolved-1" callback` is executed. Now both the callstack and microtask queue and are empty.

```
callstack: []
microtask queue: []
task queue: ["click-2"]
```

The event loop then "looks" at the task queue once again, and the cycle repeats.

```
// "click-2" is placed on the callstack
callstack: ["click-2"]
microtask queue: []
task queue: []

// Immediately resolved promise puts "resolved-2" in the microtask queue
callstack: ["click-2"]
microtask queue: ["resolved-2"]
task queue: []

// "click-2" completes ...
callstack: []
microtask queue: ["resolved-2"]
task queue: []

// "resolved-2" executes ...
callstack: ["resolved-2"]
microtask queue: []
task queue: []

// and completes
callstack: []
microtask queue: []
task queue: []
```

This would explain this output from the code snippet above

```
"hello click1"
"resolved click1"
"hello click2"
"resolved click2"
```

I would expect it to be the same then I programatically click the button with `btn.click()`.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Promise.resolve().then(function() { console.log('resolved-1'); });
  console.log('click-1');
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Promise.resolve().then(function() { console.log('resolved-2'); });
  console.log('click-2');
});

btn.click()
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Click me!</button>
```

However, the output is different.

```
"hello click1"
"hello click2"
"resolved click1"
"resolved click2"
```

Why is there a difference in the execution order when button is programatically clicked ?

Comment: `button.click()` doesn't actually click a button

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fascinating question.

First, the easy part: When you call `click`, it's a **synchronous** call triggering all of the event handlers on the button. You can see that if you add logging around the call:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Promise.resolve().then(function() { console.log('resolved-1'); });
  console.log('click-1');
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Promise.resolve().then(function() { console.log('resolved-2'); });
  console.log('click-2');
});


document.getElementById("btn-simulate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("About to call click");
  btn.click();
  console.log("Done calling click");
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Direct Click">
<input type="button" id="btn-simulate" value="Call click()">
```

Since the handlers are run synchronously, microtasks are processed only after both handlers have finished. Processing them sooner would require breaking JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics.

In contrast, when the event is [dispatched via the DOM](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm), it's more interesting: Each handler is [invoked](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#invoke-a-callback-function). Invoking a handler includes [cleaning up after running script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-a-callback), which includes doing a [microtask checkpoint](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint), running any pending microtasks. So microtasks scheduled by the handler that was invoked get run before the next handler gets run.

That's "why" they're different in one sense: Because the handler callbacks are called synchronously, in order, when you use `click()`, and so there's no opportunity to process microtasks between them.

Looking at "why" slightly differently: *Why* are the handlers called synchronously when you use `click()`? Primarily because of history, that's what early browsers did and so it can't be changed. But they're also synchronous if you use `dispatchEvent`:

```
const e = new MouseEvent("click");
btn.dispatchEvent(e);
```

In that case, the handlers are still run synchronously, because the code using it might need to look at `e` to see if the default action was prevented or similar. (It *could* have been defined differently, providing a callback or some such for when the event was done being dispatched, but it wasn't. I'd *guess* that it wasn't for either simplicity, compatibility with `click`, or both.)

Comment: To check my understanding. When I do `.click()`, it's as if I'm executing `handler1(); handler2();` to completion, after which microtasks are executed ?

Comment: Actually there are subtle differences between `click` and `dispatchEvent` (we run into those all the time when playing things at Testim and had to normalize). I'll see if I can dig up the chromium code later today to discuss. Also - note that `.click` is special and the answer to "why does it work this way" is "legacy, and because trusted events weren't always a thing" - `.click` is very special in the DOM (not to mention DOMActivate fun).

Comment: @peonicles - Right!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Oooh, I'll be interested to hear about that. You probably noticed my weasel-word "essentially." :-D I figured there wasn't a direct mapping between the two, because of the history. :-) But since `dispatchEvent` does work synchronously as well...

Comment: I'll make a gist, but as a simple one every `.click()` reports (anonymously) to home base (Google) in Chrome  (via RuntimeCallStatsCounter) in Chromium and dispatchEvent doesn't :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Ugh, not a big fan of even anonymous phone-homes like that. Thanks! Wish I were going to FullStack London to see your talk, but I doubt I will be... :-| Maybe, though...

Comment: Actually, not a lot of code, here: https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/915d0423f8bcf9db6d9fd852c28174ab

Answer (score 5):

So, Chrome answer just because it's interesting (see T.J Crowder's excellent answer for the general DOM answer).

```
btn.click();
```

Calls into `HTMLElement::click()` in C++ which is the counterpart of the DOMElement:

```js
void HTMLElement::click() {
  DispatchSimulatedClick(nullptr, kSendNoEvents,
                         SimulatedClickCreationScope::kFromScript);
}
```

Which basically does some work around dispatchMouseEvent and deals with edge cases:

```js
void EventDispatcher::DispatchSimulatedClick(
    Node& node,
    Event* underlying_event,
    SimulatedClickMouseEventOptions mouse_event_options,
    SimulatedClickCreationScope creation_scope) {
  // This persistent vector doesn't cause leaks, because added Nodes are removed
  // before dispatchSimulatedClick() returns. This vector is here just to
  // prevent the code from running into an infinite recursion of
  // dispatchSimulatedClick().
  DEFINE_STATIC_LOCAL(Persistent<HeapHashSet<Member<Node>>>,
                      nodes_dispatching_simulated_clicks,
                      (MakeGarbageCollected<HeapHashSet<Member<Node>>>()));

  if (IsDisabledFormControl(&node))
    return;

  if (nodes_dispatching_simulated_clicks->Contains(&node))
    return;

  nodes_dispatching_simulated_clicks->insert(&node);

  if (mouse_event_options == kSendMouseOverUpDownEvents)
    EventDispatcher(node, *MouseEvent::Create(event_type_names::kMouseover,
                                              node.GetDocument().domWindow(),
                                              underlying_event, creation_scope))
        .Dispatch();

  if (mouse_event_options != kSendNoEvents) {
    EventDispatcher(node, *MouseEvent::Create(event_type_names::kMousedown,
                                              node.GetDocument().domWindow(),
                                              underlying_event, creation_scope))
        .Dispatch();
    node.SetActive(true);
    EventDispatcher(node, *MouseEvent::Create(event_type_names::kMouseup,
                                              node.GetDocument().domWindow(),
                                              underlying_event, creation_scope))
        .Dispatch();
  }
  // Some elements (e.g. the color picker) may set active state to true before
  // calling this method and expect the state to be reset during the call.
  node.SetActive(false);

  // always send click
  EventDispatcher(node, *MouseEvent::Create(event_type_names::kClick,
                                            node.GetDocument().domWindow(),
                                            underlying_event, creation_scope))
      .Dispatch();

  nodes_dispatching_simulated_clicks->erase(&node);
}
```

It is entirely synchronous by design to make testing simple as well as for legacy reasons (think DOMActivate weird things).

This is just a direct call, there is no task scheduling involved. EventTarget in general is a synchronous interface that does not defer things and it predates microtick semantics and promises :]

Answer (score 4):

[dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

> **Unlike "native" events, which are fired by the DOM and invoke event
>   handlers asynchronously via the event loop, dispatchEvent invokes
>   event handlers synchronously.** All applicable event handlers will
>   execute and return before the code continues on after the call to
>   dispatchEvent.
>
> dispatchEvent is the last step of the create-init-dispatch process,
>   which is used for dispatching events into the implementation's event
>   model. The event can be created using Event constructor.

Comment: That's *half* of it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm your fan :D I love your comprehensive answers